# jQuery Best Practice for DOM traversal

Tags: jquery, dom

I am currently learning jQuery through CodeSchool.com and they mentioned that it is better to do this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".exampleclass").on('click', 'button', function() {
        //some method
    });
});
```

rather than:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".exampleclass button").on('click', function() {
        //some method
    });
});
```

They gave no reasoning for why though. As far as I can tell, there seems to be no difference between the two, in fact I find the latter to be easier.

Is there a particular reason that the first code block is more acceptable? Does it run quicker, or have any particular advantage?

Comment: *"Better"* is the wrong term to use. The former uses event delegation whereas the latter is a direct bind. They each have their place and it's up to your specific situation as to which one you use. See http://www.sitepoint.com/event-delegation-with-jquery/

Comment: @Phil Great link. Reading through it now and does an excellent job explaining the benefits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main difference is the former is equipped to handle dynamically added `button`s also since it follows the event delegation model.

The functional difference is the former attaches a click handler to each `button` element which is present in the dom at the point of the script execution, where as the later attaches a single handler to the `.exampleclass` element, when an event occurs within the element and it reaches the `exampleclass` element via event propagation it tests the target element agains the selector passed in this case `button` if the test is successful then registered handler is called

Comment: Yes, I was going to add that the jQuery documentation says `If the selector is null or omitted, the event is always triggered when it reaches the selected element.`

Comment: Ah okay. That's huge. Definitely good to know. Thanks for the quick response Arun!